# How to ? RSPEC/GUARD/SPRING combo to run all tests at the same time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spring, rspec, guard

I seem to be running only one test at a time. is there a way to run them all. i have like 15 tests ( right now) and I constantly have to back out of guard to run them all.

Comment: Yes... it has been a long... long ...  day..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run all tests, just hit `enter` in the Guard console.